# How to run spring source code in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

how to run **spring source code** in eclipse or sts.
I import https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration under sub module spring-integration-core. so, how to run this code.
please give solution because i am trying to contribute to spring projects if any idea.
Thank in adavance

Comment: If you don't know how to compile and run the tests you might want to first reconsider to contribute? There isn't anything to run because it isn't a program. Yu can build the project and create a jar which will run the tests.

Comment: Thank you. There is no maven or gradle support for this then how to add all required dependencies. when i tried to execute test cases it asking to set run configuration.